# UK spouse visa questions

Tags: uk-visa, marriage

I intend to apply for UK spouse visa. My wife is English; she is exempt from financial requirements: she's on Personal Independence Payment (PIP) and Employment and Support Allowance (ESA).

I've known her since September 2017, but we lost our chat history from September through December 2017. We have a lots of pictures of us together, ones from our marriage, and with family and friends.

The problem is that my wife is estranged from her family so I don't have any contact with them. Is that going to be a problem and would the Home Office doubt our relationship?

I am going to apply this November. Is this going to be enough time to prove that we are in a valid relationship?

Additional notes: If I am paying my wife that's to help her because we share everything so I don't think it should be payment to get visa and I said my wife estranged because this factor make it worst. I am going because my wife needs me she is alone there in addition I am English teacher and I work

1. her friends didn't attend the wedding ceremony
2. we have been together more than 1 year
3. we lost the beginning of our conversation when we still didn't met so I can't cover that period by pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Home Office is perfectly capable of doubting your relationship even if you have been married and living together for 40 years, and have grown-up children.  I don't see why your wife being estranged from her family should make that more likely.  (Sorry, I have a very low opinion of the Home Office.)

The Home Office may be concerned that you are paying your wife (who, if she is on PIP+ESA is obviously not well off), in order to get a visa to the UK.  The following evidence is likely to be helpful:

- Evidence that her friends attended your wedding.  (If it was not in the UK, it might be helpful to show that they funded the trip themselves.)
- Evidence that you have been together more than a year; if you don't have chat logs before January 2018 then just tell them you have lost the earlier ones, and point out that the logs from Jan 2018 don't look like people who have only just met (... assuming they don't of course).
- Photos from before Jan 2018, will be particularly helpful (filling in the gap).
- Evidence of continuing contact after the wedding.
- An explanation of why you are currently living apart.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... 1- her friends didn't attend the wedding ceremony. 2- we have been together more than 1 year 3- we lost  the beginning of our  conversation when we still didn't met so I can't cover that period by pictures

Comment: The fact that her friends didn't attend the wedding does make it easier for a cynical immigration officer to believe this is a fake relationship.  So does the fact you are sending your wife money.  (Yes, yes, *of course* you are looking after your wife in any way you can - in English you would have sworn to take her "for richer, for poorer, in sickness and in health" - just look at it through the cynic's eyes though.)

Comment: Look martin I know my wife since September 2017 she has a mental illness after I knew her for that all her family and friends left her alone... now i am struggling and very worried to see her alone there I know it's personal info but I have to explain to find the right answer and help ... I tried to talk to all her family to come back to talk to her but even they refuse to talk to me .. for that i am rushing to apply coz her illness need someone next her ...in addition her medicine are prohibited in my country ... so I am stuck between this and that ... or I would bring her here

Comment: @Aladinhenchiri you have enough money to send some of it to your wife.  Do you have enough money to spend on a UK immigration lawyer?  Having a lawyer prepare your application would probably cost a few thousand pounds, but you may be able to find less comprehensive help for a few hundred pounds.

Comment: No  you know lawyers look just for money and they can make a lots of mistakes in the application in addition to the big amount that they demand ... I know what to do and all the proceess I am worried just from the point that there's no one from the part of my wife is in contact with me or even with her ... my big problem is I can't leave her there alone with her illness I am worried from suicide honestly

Comment: @Aladinhenchiri you may have grounds for a human rights claim.  I personally wouldn't try anything like that without a lawyer.  But if you don't want to pay for expert advice you should just proceed with your application.  People here won't have as much experience as an immigration lawyer, and our opinions (for example, about whether the home office will question your relationship or whether any given period of time before your application will be significant) won't be particularly useful.

Comment: @phoog thank you for the answer .. may I ask you how to exploit the human rights claim how to do that I have no idea about this point if you can explain more how to proceed with it

Comment: @Aladinhenchiri I really don't know much about it. It may be that it can be raised only on appeal, though that would seem odd.  Like I said, it might be a good idea to talk to a lawyer.